# SSSD service not working to join Active Directory - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: active-directory, sssd

I'm a new user of Ubuntu. I want that my Ubuntu desktop could join Windows AD domain.When I try to join Active Directory with the procedure [SSSD and Active Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html#sssd-ad-sssdconfig) from Ubuntu Documentation. I'm in front a problem with SSSD service startup

```
sudo systemctl start sssd.service
```

When I enter this command, I have an error response :

```
Job for sssd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status sssd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is what I got when I run command `systemctl status sssd.service` :

```
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-01-08 09:57:17 EST; 1h 48min ago
  Process: 10203 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sssd -i ${DEBUG_LOGGER} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 10203 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 08 09:57:16 ubuntu-terminal sssd[10207]: Starting up
Jan 08 09:57:16 ubuntu-terminal sssd[10208]: Starting up
Jan 08 09:57:16 ubuntu-terminal sssd[10209]: Starting up
Jan 08 09:57:16 ubuntu-terminal sssd[10210]: Starting up
Jan 08 09:57:17 ubuntu-terminal sssd[be[10211]: Starting up
Jan 08 09:57:17 ubuntu-terminal sssd[be[10211]: Failed to read keytab [default]: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
Jan 08 09:57:17 ubuntu-terminal sssd[10203]: Exiting the SSSD. Could not restart critical service [COPICOM.LOCAL].
Jan 08 09:57:17 ubuntu-terminal systemd[1]: sssd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 08 09:57:17 ubuntu-terminal systemd[1]: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 08 09:57:17 ubuntu-terminal systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
```

Someone can help me to know why this happening ?

Thanks !